# Get webpack error after creating next.js app. How can I fix it?

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm trying to create nextjs app with

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

on my hosting provider. After that I run

```
npm run dev
```

The app seems to be started, but I get following errors:

testh3@vs828:/var/www/testh3/test.gsmcounters.com$ npm run dev

> test.gsmcounters.com@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/var/www'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/var/                                                                                       www'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/var/www'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/var/                                                                                       www'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/var/www'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/var/                                                                                       www'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/var/www'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/var/                                                                                       www'
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1967 ms (165 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 38 ms (132 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 18 ms (33 modules)
 [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
 [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1084 ms (194 modules)
 [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
 [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies

It is unclear for me why webpack trying to look folders, that does not belonges to my app. How can I change that behaviour to fix error. Or maybe this error somehow connected to my provider's environment?